# Concurrency exception not jumping in Entity framework Core and myslq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a concurrencyException whenever two users save the same record but nothing is happening

I created an entity in the DB with a property called `rowversion` and configure it the next:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>()
        .Property(a => a.RowVersion)
        .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

As it is myslq I cannot use `TimeStamp` I tried with the new `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute but nothing happened either.

note: I ran migrations too.

When I do two calls at the same time, The first one gets saved and the second one returns a successfull but it does not fail (0 rows updated)
As mentioned, It does not update anything in the DB but It does not fail, I am following the Microsoft documentation I was expecting it to fail.
How can i configure it to fail?

Thanks.

Comment: When you do two calls _at the same time_, how can there be a _first_ and a _second_? 
How do you do those two calls at "the same time"?
Concurrency is usually very hard to test for - I can think of having tens, hundreds or thousands  of instances of clients doing multiple identical calls in order to "force" concurrency issues. 
(Of course, just two human users in one production environment works every time...)

Comment: @oerkelens my understanding based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations  ; is that If i do a read, and then wait 20 seconds (thread.sleep) while modifiying the value in the meantime, the call must fail because there is nothing to update. in fact, nothing gets updated, bu the call does not fail. which is the part I do not fully get.